# .htacces rewrite condition not hitting?

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

Lets say I have a two websites www.sample.com and files.sample.com.

In an .htaccess file within the webroot of www.sample.com, I have the following:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine on

  RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^files\/uploads [NC]
  RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://files.website.com/$1 [NC,L]
</IfModule>
```

The desired result is to have all requests of `www.sample.com/files/uploads/file.xml` or `www.sample.com/files/uploads/subfolder/file.json` get `302 redirected` to `files.sample.com/files/uploads/file.xml` and `www.sample.com/files/uploads/subfolder/file.json`, respectively.

However, I can't get the rule to fire. The directory "files" does not exist on the www.sample.com website at all.

Could anyone give me a little help as to why the

Comment: Are both domain points to the same wwwroot?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want REQUEST_URI not QUERY_STRING.

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/files\/uploads [NC]
```

Also note the leading slash.

Answer (score 0):

Did you turn on mod_rewrite in your apache config?
Also yor change '^files/uploads' to ^/files/uploads and QUERY_STRING to PATH_INFO.
QUERY_STRING - this is all data after '?' character.